# Is there a method to avoid the overlap of words in my word search game?

Tags: python-3.x, search, cpu-word

In this function the program gets four words entered by the user into a list and randomly puts them in the 10x10 matrix. The problem is sometimes words from horizontal/vertical/diagonal overlap each other due to `random.randiant`.

Is there a way to avoid this happening?

```py
    def add(word, puzzle):
    temp = random.randint(0, 2)
    if temp == 0:
        row = random.randint(0, 14)
        column = random.randint(0, 12-len(word))
        for i in range(0, len(word)):
            puzzle[row][column+i] = word[i]
    elif temp == 1:
        column = random.randint(0, 14)
        row = random.randint(0, 14-len(word))
        for i in range(0, len(word)):
            puzzle[row+i][column] = word[i]
    else:
        row = random.randint(0, 14-len(word))
        for i in range(0, len(word)):
            puzzle[row+i][row+i+1] = word[i]
```

Comment: So the question is, that you want to randomize indexes of each letter of the word so that characters don't overlap?

Comment: In this function the program gets the four words entered by the user into a list and randomly puts them in the 10x10 matrix.
The problem is sometimes words from horizontal/vertical/diagonal overlap each other